# Given a link to the pdf file in the html code. But it is unable to open it

Tags: javascript, html

```
<li><a href='fileName.pdf' download > Web Interface Help </a> </li>
```

This is how I am trying to access the file. But every time it says no file exists. But the file is in the same location as this html page.

Comment: Double check the spelling of the file name, especially make sure there are no white spaces in the name.

Comment: Well, the issue is either that your file isn't the right place, the file name is incorrect (hint: it's case sensitive in most cases), or some sort of permissions or configuration problem preventing access.  In any case, the HTML snippet won't help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

simple syntax error

```
<a href="fileName.pdf">download</a>
```